# How to change production endpoint port on wso2 api manager?

Tags: wso2, port, endpoint

I am testing Wso2 Api Manager on Ubuntu 18.04. When I created the demo phone verify soap to rest api, the production end point port shows 8281.

Currently on ubuntu I am serving a dart server which uses same port. And all the configuration port from 8080 to 8484 allocated to for my existing server.

My question is how to change production end point port to something different like 9090?

Example:

**Default Settings show:**

```
http://localhost:8281/phoneverify/1.0.0
```

**And I need to change to:**

```
http://localhost:9090/phoneverify/1.0.0
```

Every time I need to run the server I need to publish my endpoint to use port 9090. How do I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the port offset to 810 in AM_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml. Then all the ports will get offset from 810.

Comment: Thanks Pubci, if I set port ofset 810, and everytime start the wso2 server does it mean my publish enpoint serves me on port 9090?

Answer (score 1):

Setting offsets in carbon. xml would work, but it will move all other ports as well. I'd sugest using two other ways we commonly use

1. have an http reverse proxy

   You can have a reverse proxy (httpd, ngix,..) to listen to any port defined and forward requests to the target endpoint
2. you can set the nio port in the file repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server. xml